# Modifying Gurobi objective function for MIP scheduling problem in python

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm getting started using the Gurobi optimizer for scheduling and need a little help making things more sophisticated.

Here's a working example of scheduling 3 events with the constraint that events can not be in sequential time slots and the cost rises linearly with time.

```
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

m = gp.Model("example")
days = np.arange(10)
sched = m.addMVar(10, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
# Demand 3 scheduled events
m.addConstr(sched.sum() == 3)
# Constrain that can't schedule consecutive time slots
m.addConstrs(sched[i+1] @ sched[i] == 0 for i in range(9))
# Cost increases linearly with time
cost = np.arange(1, 11)
# Objective function
m.setObjective(sched @ cost, GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()
print(m.X)
```

This gives the correct result: `[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

I'd now like to expand my objective function to reward scheduling gaps of N days (e.g., there is a -20 cost for every time events are scheduled 4 days apart). I can make an array of all the possible schedule gaps with `gap_array = days[:, np.newaxis] - days`. Do I brute force loop through that and each spot where gap_array is my goal gap add a term to the objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to measure something for every combination of N days. For example, for 4 days difference, you will need a term for (0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8) and (5,9). Internally, the solver will add a new binary variable for each of these combinations, but you could stay with your current style by writing something like:

```
m.setObjective(sched@cost -10 * sched[:6]@sched[4:])
```

Comment: Very nice one-line solution. Looks like the multiplication has to be on the other side to make it work, `m.setObjective(sched@cost - sched[:6]@sched[4:]*10)`